# What punctuation would you invent to solve your issues?

Tags: language, punctuation

**What punctuation is missing  from English that might solve your writing issues?**

People may be able to come up with established ones that meet your criteria, such as the /s to indicate "that last bit was sarcastic," but what punctuation confusions would *you* like to solve?

I see a related question of "how would one use punctuation to indicate tone changes?"  and "indicating different modes of speech, both translated and telepathic" and "how to indicate the slightest pause in dialogue."

Perhaps English needs to add something, typographically.  (And we can make it catch on!)

*I'll answer with mine, but I'd love to see more.*

Comment: I don't see this as on-topic for this stack, it is fishing for a conversation, not presenting a soluble problem many other writers might encounter. There are hundreds of special characters that could be used in writing for some kind of in-world punctuation. I don't think the world of teaching will change to embrace some punctuation mark that might be used once in thousand books or only in fiction about telepathy.

Comment: I tried to delete it, but it wouldn't let me. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This is one thing I think English needs: the "**Ammoc**" -- it looks like a comma, but backwards.

It's used to indicate when one feels that for breath or speaking issues, **a pause is needed, but it grammatically does NOT fit the rules of using a comma**.

Often this is when the subject phrase is pretty long, so when speaking, one adds a break before the verb.

I often see a need for this is corporate-ese: speakers often pause after each phrase, whether or not it's a full clause that would have punctuation surrounding it.

This could also be used to indicate that small pause in dialog -- a little less intense of one than an em-dash or ellipses.

Comment: There is a breath mark for musical notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breath_mark (sadly, they make it look like just a regular comma)

Comment: I totally agree.  When speaking, we use pauses not only for breathing, but also to give the listener a chance to parse the works most recently said, build links between those words, and separation between then and what follows, even in cases where a comma is not grammatically standard.